# Getting the KVM VM domain name in a C program using libvirt API

Tags: c, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm writing a C program and I'd like to get the KVM VM's domain name.  Is there an easy way to do that?  I have the VM id of the machine and can get a pointer to the virDomainInfo struct.  I know I can do it with the command, `virsh domname <id>`, but I can't seem to find a libvirt API so I can do it programmatically.  After some digging I found the struct info for the virDomain.  Would it be an option to grab it from there?

```
struct _virDomain {
   virObject object;
   virConnectPtr conn;                  /* pointer back to the connection */
   char *name;                          /* the domain external name */
   int id;                              /* the domain ID */
   unsigned char uuid[VIR_UUID_BUFLEN]; /* the domain unique identifier */
 };
```

below is the code I'm using.

```
virConnectPtr conn = virConnectOpen(connString);
virDomainPtr domainPtr = virDomainLookupByID(conn, vmid);
```

Not sure where to go from here.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just browsing through the libvirt API I found [virDomainGetName](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainGetName), which seems like it may be exactly what you want:

> virDomainGetName
>
> const char *  virDomainGetName    (virDomainPtr domain)
>
> Get the public name for that domain
>
> domain
>       a domain object Returns
>       a pointer to the name or NULL, the string need not be deallocated its lifetime will be the same as the domain object.

I through together some sample code:

```
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
          virConnectPtr c;
          virDomainPtr d;
          char *name;

          c = virConnectOpen(NULL);
          d = virDomainLookupByID(c, 2);
          name = virDomainGetName(d);

          printf("name of domain %d is %s\n", 2, name);
          return 0;
  }
```

Comment: wow I don't how I missed that.  must have been staring at it too long.  thanks.